# SPICE model of DRAM

Tags: memory, spice, dram

Is there a SPICE model for DRAM developed? I am interested in any type of model at any level starting from DRAM memory cell and towards to whole memory VLSI circuit. I am seeking for a DRAM operation tutorial that includes examples utilizing SPICE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is frankly a bit too broad (although you may not realize that yet). But since you're literally asking for any SPICE model for any DRAM circuit, [the Micron page for one of their many DRAM chips [MT41J256M16HA-093] has a HSPICE model](http://www.micron.com/parts/dram/ddr3-sdram/mt41j256m16ha-093). HSPICE is a dialect/implementation of SPICE.