# SPICE model for DRAM transistor

Tags: transistors, spice, modeling, dram

My research group wants to investigate how powder delivery network (PDN) noise (such as ground bounce) can affect the retention time of DRAM cells. The idea is that the power noise increases the leakage from the bit capacitor and causes it to require a higher refresh rate (or suffer from bit errors).

The problem is that the only transistor models I can find are for bulk CMOS which are too leaky for DRAM. According to Jacob et al. [1] (Section 8.2.1) the leakage through a DRAM transistor should be on the order of 1 fA, but the bulk CMOS models have leakage on the order of 1 pA (three orders of magnitude too high). Can anyone point me to any reasonable DRAM transistor model for this work? I've been looking for days with no results.

[1] Jacob, Bruce, Spencer Ng, and David Wang. Memory systems: cache, DRAM, disk. p. 356, Morgan Kaufmann, 2010.

Comment: Are you sure that the 1pA isn't caused by the simulator adding a 1 Teraohm resistor to ground on the floating node ? In my experience some simulators do that when a floating node is detected. Usually there's a property you can set to increase this resistor value. Since DRAM is used on a chip you would need a designkit with models from a DRAM manufacturer. This is not something they will share easily with you I guess. I would take an existing  model and hack it but that might not give an accurate representation.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use your existing model for the FETs, but scale everything else. You'd increase capacitor values by 1000, as well as charge/discharge currents, but cut power circuit inductances and resistances by 1000, so the effects of the larger currents are reduced.

Comment: If you have access to IEEEXplore, there are some promising looking papers: "An efficient statistical model using electrical tests for GHz CMOS devices" and "Design and Characterization of a Multilevel DRAM".

Comment: You can get [hspice models for a lot of DRAM devices](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145491/spice-model-of-dram), but they have encrypted data in their files, so the transistor model[s] aren't transparent/available.